# how to order results from a table in MYSQL by the same order as when added to the table?

Tags: mysql

If I added a record yesterday and one today, how do I order the results by 'select * from table_name' by getting the entry added today first and then the older ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your primary key field is an auto-incremented integer, then you can do the following:

`SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY pk_column DESC`

If you're not using an auto-incremented integer for your primary key, then you'll need to do as Andre suggested and timestamp your rows.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to timestamp and order by it, or order by a field with auto increment or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Unless records are deleted, they are stored right in the order they were inserted.
If records are deleted, new records are inserted not in a subsequent order. You then need to explicitly order by an "auto-incremented" ID field or a timestamp or something similar (if your table structure does provide any of these).